# Convert from Caml.List function to Base module

Tags: list, ocaml

I am a total beginner in OCaml.

I need to convert an function from Caml module to the Base module.

I thought I could do it by removing the Caml. but it is not working as there is an type error.

This is my code

```
type 'a t = Node of 'a list * ('a arc list) [@@deriving show] and 'a arc = char * 'a t [@@deriving show]

let rec size (t1 : 'a t)=
  let aux (n : int)(x : 'a arc) = n + size (snd x) in
    match t1 with
    | Node([], [])     -> 0
    | Node(_ :: _, []) -> 1
    | Node([], l)      -> Caml.List.fold_left aux 0 l 
    | Node(_ :: _, l)  -> Caml.List.fold_left aux 1 l ;;
```

and I got this error by removing the Caml.

```
File "sort.ml", line 47, characters 41-44:
47 |     | Node([], l)      -> List.fold_left aux 0 l 
                                              ^^^
Error: This expression has type int -> 'a arc -> int
       but an expression was expected of type 'b list
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/List/index.html#val-fold_left)?

Comment: Yes already tried, before asking it here. But reading it didn't helped me anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Base library](https://opensource.janestreet.com/base/) provides the [List.fold](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/List/index.html#val-fold) function, which you shall use as a general iterator<sup>1</sup>. It has a type that differs from the type of [List.fold_left](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_left) from the OCaml standard library and that means it shall be used differently. Namely, it uses [labels](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#s%3Alabels) to pass arguments to the function and the order of the arguments differ also (to conform to the Janestreet coding conventions). In your case, to make it work, you need to use labels, when you call this function, e.g.,

```
let rec size (t1 : 'a t)=
  let aux (n : int)(x : 'a arc) = n + size (snd x) in
  match t1 with
  | Node([], [])     -> 0
  | Node(_ :: _, []) -> 1
  | Node([], l)      -> List.fold ~f:aux ~init:0 l
  | Node(_ :: _, l)  -> List.fold ~f:aux ~init:1 l ;;
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> You can use [List.fold_left](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/List/index.html#val-fold_left) as an alias to `List.fold` but it is not recommended and the only difference is the name, the type is still the same.